# Bash: command grouping with curly braces inside subshell

Tags: bash, grouping, subshell

When I'm trying something like this:

```
( echo && { echo ; echo } )
```

I'm getting:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

I'm sure that I need to use subshell. And I'm sure that I need grouping inside of it. So how do I avoid the syntax error?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A command list must be terminated with a `;` or a newline.

Instead say:

```
( echo && { echo ; echo ; } )
                       ^^^
                        |======= Add this
```

From `info bash`:

```
   { list; }
          list  is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list
          must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This  is  known
          as  a  group  command. ...
```